# XSD validation error in #AnonType_Apps

Tags: xsd

When I tried to validate my XSD it gives the error

> S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_Apps' Is Invalid.
>   Element 'sequence' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.

don't know what should be done

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name ="Apps">
   <xs:complexType>
       <xs:attribute name ="List_Type" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
               <xs:enumeration value="new releases"/>
               <xs:enumeration value="top rated"/>
               <xs:enumeration value="category list"/>
           </xs:restriction>
           </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name ="Server_IP" type="xs:string" fixed="10.144.50.55"/>
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name ="App" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="20">
           <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:attribute name ="device_type" use="optinal" >
                 <xs:simpleType>
                 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                       <xs:enumeration value="tablet"/>
                       <xs:enumeration value="phone"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
                 <xs:attribute name ="app_id" type="xs:string"/>  
                 <xs:attribute name ="installed" type="xs:boolean" default="false"/>
                 <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name ="app_name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                 <xs:element name ="catogry" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"></xs:element>
                 <xs:element name ="version" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                 <xs:element name ="description" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                 <xs:element name ="reviews" use="required">
                    <xs:complexType>
                       <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element name ="review" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                          <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:all>
                             <xs:element name ="reviewer_name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                             <xs:element name ="review_date">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                      <xs:pattern value="\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}"/>
                                   </xs:restriction>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                             </xs:element>
                             </xs:all>
                           </xs:complexType>
                       </xs:element>
                       </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name ="review_time">
                   <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:pattern value="\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{}"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                   </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
               <xs:element name ="content" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
               <xs:element name ="rating">
                  <xs:complexType>                                
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
                         <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                         <xs:maxInclusive value="5" />
                     </xs:restriction>
                 </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a `complexType` element, the content model comes first and the attribute declarations come last.  Move the outermost `sequence` element to make it the first child of the complex type.

You might want to try finding a syntax-aware editor in which to edit schema documents, to alert you to problems of this kind.

Other syntactic issues in this fragment:

- Other `complexType` elements have the same syntax error of putting their attribute declarations first.
- If you want the type of `rating` to be a restriction of xs:float, then you want it to have a simple type, not a complex type.
- Ditto for `review_time` and `review_date`.
- The pattern on the type of `review_time` is not a legal regular expression:  braces may contain information on the minimum and/or maximum occurrences of (strings matching) a subexpression, in a variety of forms, but they must contain *something*, so `\d{}` is not a legal expression.  Drop the empty braces, or make it `\d{1}` if you like, or make it say what you want.
- The `xs:element` element has no attribute named `use`; I think you may mean to say `<xs:element name="reviews" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">` ...
- The `use` attribute does not accept the value `optinal`.

Get an editor!

Comment: thanx it's valid now =] about the editor i'm using jEdit i know it's bad but i'm downloading a better editor it's hard to find a good one for Mac

Answer (score 0):

Your xs:sequence element needs to follow immidiately on the complexType element.

Your review_date and review_time elements should be a simpleType with a restriction.

If you fix those issues your xsd seems validd.